# C error C2040 'f': 'errno_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'FILE *'

Tags: c

Any help will be much appreciated. I am writing this code however I keep getting this error and I am unsure of how to deal with it. I've looked online about the C2040 but it still doesn't help me sort out my problem.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

struct Employer
{
char name[50];
int house;
int age;
};

int main()
{
struct Employer employee1;

printf("Employee information:\n\n");

printf("Please input your house number: ");
scanf_s("%d", &employee1.house);

printf("\n");

printf("Please enter your age: ");
scanf_s("%d", &employee1.age);

printf("Please input your name: ");
scanf_s("%s\n", &employee1.name, 50);

getchar();
getchar();

{
    FILE *f;
    errno_t f = fopen_s(&f, "Employee details.txt", "w");

    printf("Employees' name: %s", employee1.name);
    printf("Employees' house number: %d", employee1.house);
    printf("Employees' age: %d", employee1.age);
}
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Look at your code again, and again and again until you see it. I doubt that's the only error you get, you should probably get something about redefining `f`.

Comment: Read [ask] and format your code properly.

Comment: This `scanf_s("%s\n", &employee1.name, 50);` doesn't look good as well.

Comment: I am using visual studios and says that scanf() is unsafe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the name `f` for `errno_t` as you have already used it for `FILE*`.

So change `errno_t f = fopen_s(....` to `errno_t error = fopen_s(....`